# Фильтрация с помощью WP_Query в WordPress

Tags: sql, wordpress, оптимизация, filter

Добрый день.

Есть задача сделать кастомный фильтр в админ панели для продуктов.

Продуктов более 600 000 позиций.

Код:

```
/**
 * Custom date filter
 */
if( isset( $_GET['parser_upload_date_from'] ) && $_GET['parser_upload_date_from']
    || isset( $_GET['parser_upload_date_to'] ) && $_GET['parser_upload_date_to'] ) {
    $from = $_GET['parser_upload_date_from']? $_GET['parser_upload_date_from']: '2010-01-01';
    $to   = $_GET['parser_upload_date_to']? $_GET['parser_upload_date_to']: '3000-01-01';

    // Get valid posts for date products
    $products = $wpdb->get_col( "select `post_id` from `sfp_products_meta` where str_to_date(`created_at`,'%Y-%m-%d') between '{$from}' and '{$to}' " );

    if( ! $products ) {
        $products = array(0);
    }

    // Set query
    $query->query_vars['post__in'] = $products;
}
```

Сейчас вордпресс не справляется с нагрузкой и сервер падает.

Есть ли идеи как можно оптимизировать данный фильтр ?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался )

Код:

```
/**
* Custom date filter
*/
if( isset( $_GET['parser_upload_date_from'] ) && $_GET['parser_upload_date_from']
|| isset( $_GET['parser_upload_date_to'] ) && $_GET['parser_upload_date_to'] ) {

// Get valid for date products
add_filter( 'posts_where', function ( $where, \WP_Query $q ) {
    $from = $_GET['parser_upload_date_from']? $_GET['parser_upload_date_from']: '2010-01-01';
    $to   = $_GET['parser_upload_date_to']? $_GET['parser_upload_date_to']: '3000-01-01';

    $where .= " AND STR_TO_DATE(wp_posts.post_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '{$from}' AND '{$to}'";
    return $where;
}, 10, 2 );
}
```